# How to verify a link text value in tosca which doesn't have an innertext

Tags: tosca, actionmode

How can I verify the text "download quote" of the link Download Quote in tricentis vehicle insurance application.

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RerWR.png

Innertext is not present for this particular link.Please help to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check with the DefaultName Property if it contains the required text Or may be you can search the same in its Parent control.
I hope you get them ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the Xpath for the same and get the content value after it